# How to fetch a large dataset in R from Google Analytics?

Tags: r, google-analytics

When I fetch a small data set, say 2000 observations, in R using googleAnalyticsR from google analytics, everything works well.

```
    df <- google_analytics(id=ga_id,
                           start="2017-12-01",
                           end="2017-12-31",
                           metrics="ga:users",
                           dimensions="ga:dimension1, ga:longitude, ga:latitude",
                           max=10000)
```

But when I needed to fetch a  bigger data set with 20000 observations, the same code failed and error returned:

> Batching data into [2] calls.
>     Request to profileId:  ()
>     Error in f(content, ...) : Invalid dimension or metric:

How can I solve this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a provision to run your code in batches. I use 'rga' library and I download huge data in batches, and data frame that comes out usually has all observations. Here is a slight modification. Please let me know if it doesn't work.

```
df <- ga$getData(id, batch =TRUE,
                           start="2017-01-01",
                           end="2017-12-31",
                           metrics="ga:users",
                           dimensions="ga:dimension1, ga:longitude,ga:latitude",
                           max=10000)
```

It is from a git [version](https://github.com/skardhamar/rga) of the library. Very sorry I did not mention this earlier. I use this so much, I forgot it isn't part of the CRAN version.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sree. But when I add "batch=TRUE" statement in the googleAnalyticsR library, error occurred "unused argument (batch = TRUE)". When I use  "batch=TRUE" statement in the rga library "df <- ga$getData(...), Error: object 'ga' not found. If I adjust the code to ...df <- df$getData()..., Error: "Error in df$getData : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable".

Comment: I edited my answer HW-Scientist. Please see. Sorry for my forgetfulness.

Comment: I finally was able to get a data set with 20000 observations. I did two adjustments: 1) Added statement: rga.open(instance="ga") before defining the dataframe. 2) Adjusted the date format to: start.date="2017-01-01", end.date="2017-12-31", which is slightly different from the googleAnalyticsR package.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set max to -1, then it fetches all results.  You don't need to set batches or page sizes etc. , it does that for you.

Here are some examples from the [website](http://code.markedmondson.me/googleAnalyticsR/v4.html):

```
# 1000 rows only
thousand <- google_analytics(ga_id, 
                             date_range = c("2017-01-01", "2017-03-01"), 
                             metrics = "sessions", 
                             dimensions = "date")

# 2000 rows
twothousand <- google_analytics(ga_id, 
                             date_range = c("2017-01-01", "2017-03-01"), 
                             metrics = "sessions", 
                             dimensions = "date",
                             max = 2000)  

# All rows
alldata <- google_analytics(ga_id, 
                             date_range = c("2017-01-01", "2017-03-01"), 
                             metrics = "sessions", 
                             dimensions = "date",
                             max = -1)
```